# C# Console Application phonebook arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, addressbook

I am told to design a phonebook which will use 2D array to store Name and Phone numbers in type : string .
It should have the functions like add, remove, print methods.

I am yet struggling in this array. I do not know how to fill the whole of array members with "none" whenever a record for name is not present and "000" for its number.

by default, i need it to have this printed:
(20 records of none 000)
none 000
none 000
none 000
...
none 000
none 000
none 000

I came up with:

```
string[,] db = new db[20,2];
```

I am not sure though if its the right, but I just want a 2D array which has 20 rows and 2 columns.

Then I wanna use for or foreach loop to fill the elements by none and 000:

```
for (int i=0; i<db.Length/2; i++)
     for (int j=0; j<db.Length/20; j++)
```

Could you help me with filling that?
Thanks

Comment: Homework or real life? If real life, then don't use a multi-dimensional array, use a Dictionary, collection of objects, or some other better data structure.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Address {
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string Phone {get; set; }
}

List<Address> addressBook = new List<Address>();

// Do stuff with your list
```

No need to use an array.

Comment: I bet it's homework with a constraint not to use classes.  Still, you're right

Comment: Yeah, now that I re-read the question it feels that way. Well, nothing wrong with homework but then this won't be very useful to him if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

The loop you're looking for to initialize the array would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    db[i,0] = "none";
    db[i,1] = "000";
}
```